# Is one dll can be both dotnet tool and nuget?

Tags: c#, nuget, dotnet-tool

Creating a dotnet tool is like creating a nuget package. We create it by `dotnet pack` command and publish him to `nuget` feed.

But we can't use it as nuget package in our C# project, although it is a `nuget`!

Can I create a one Console Application project and publish it as `dotnet tool`, and then use it as nuget package in a C# project?

Answer (score -1):

Publish your tool as NuGet package, add the dir you published to to the NuGet soruces (VS:Tool>Options>NuGet>big-green-plus-button).
Open the NuGet package Manager in the Project you want the use the NuGet package and select your source, wait for NuGet to load, and then install the NuGet tool you published

Comment: So that is how to publish tool as nuget. But after these steps, can I both install this nuget as dotnet global tool and nuget?